# How to fix 'warning: missing %end (%hook opened at Tweak.x:14 extends to EOF)' error when I already have %end

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, objective-c++, theos, tweak

I've created a tweak via Zane Helton's online video tutorials. 
I've gone over my own code multiple times to try and figure out why
this is happening, 
I've googled it to no avail and am just trying to figure out what 
the cause is so I can prevent it if it happens again.

I've moved things around, I have deleted all my comments to
see if that's what it was. 
I've googled it and everyone else has just misspelled %end...
I've moved %end around and have no clue what is causing this...

```
@interface BCBatteryDeviceController {
    NSArray *_sortedDevices;
}
+(id)sharedInstance;
@end

@interface BCBatteryDevice {
  long long _percentCharge;
  NSString *_name;
}
@end

%hook UIViewController

- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent  
animated:(BOOL)flag           
completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
  //no code would run without orig
  if ([viewControllerToPresent isKindOfClass[UIAlertController class]]) {
    UIAlertController *ac = (UIAlertController *)viewControllerToPresent; 

    BCBatteryDeviceController *bcb = [%c(BCBatteryDeviceController) sharedInstance]; 

    NAArrray *devices = MSHookIvar<NSArray *>(bcb, "_sortedDevices");

    NSMutableString *newMessage = [NSMutableString new];

    for (BCBatteryDevice *device in devices) { 
      NSString *deviceName = MSHookIvar<NSString *>(device, "_name");
      long long deviceCharge = MSHookIvar<long long>(device, "_percentCharge");

      [newMessage appendString:@"%@ : %lld%%\n", deviceName, deviceCharge]; 
    }

    [ac setMessage:newMessage];
    return %orig(ac, flag, completion); 
  } else {
    return %orig; 
  }
}


%end
```

Error log:

```
Hunters-MacBook-Pro:redrectangle shutthu$ make package
> Making all for tweak RedRectangle…
==> Preprocessing Tweak.x…
logos: warnings being treated as errors
Tweak.x:47: warning: missing %end (%hook opened at Tweak.x:14 extends to EOF)
make[3]: *** [/Users/shutthu/Desktop/iOS9JBTweak/redrectangle/.theos/obj/debug/armv7,/Tweak.x.m] Error 1
rm /Users/shutthu/Desktop/iOS9JBTweak/redrectangle/.theos/obj/debug/armv7,/Tweak.x.m
make[2]: *** [/Users/shutthu/Desktop/iOS9JBTweak/redrectangle/.theos/obj/debug/armv7,/RedRectangle.dylib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [RedRectangle.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

My makefile had a , in it for the archetype. I saw it in the error log, thought that's how you put it in there :/. I had two in a comma so....

If anyone comes across this error and doesn't know what it means, check the makefile and make sure there's no commas in the

```
ARCHS = armv7 arm64
```

like this:

```
ARCHS = armv7, arm64
```

Sorry everyone for wasting your time. :/